# Sorting a List of Integers and Strings by integer descending order in VB

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have to make this program that sorts the high scores of a game and then displays them biggest to smallest with the username USING LISTS. So far i have written:

```
Public highscore As New List(Of HighScores)

highscore.Add(New HighScores("Jeremias", 6))
highscore.Add(New HighScores("Tom", 1))
highscore.Add(New HighScores("sdf", 5))
highscore.Add(New HighScores("asfd", 1))

highscore.Sort()
highscore.Reverse()

Console.WriteLine("------High Scores-----")
For Each scores In highscore
     Console.WriteLine(scores)
Next
Console.WriteLine("----------------------")
```

And the HighScores Class:

```
Public Class HighScores
    Public name As String
    Public score As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal score As Integer)
        Me.name = name
        Me.score = score
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0}, {1}", Me.name, Me.score)
    End Function
End Class
```

Usually i would just use .Sort() and .Reverse() to sort the list, but in this case i don't think i can do this. Any ideas how i can rewrite this/just sort the list easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify how to sort a `List(Of T)` in various ways.  The simplest would be like so:

```
highscore.Sort(Function(x, y) y.score.CompareTo(x.score))
```

That uses the overload of `Sort` that takes a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate and uses a Lambda expression for that delegate.  Note that the Lambda parameters are `x` and `y` and the body calls `CompareTo` on the `score` of `y`.  That is critical because that's what makes the sort happen in descending order and negates the need to call `Reverse`.

Note that you could use a named method instead of a Lambda.  Such a method would look like this:

```
Private Function CompareHighScoresByScoreDescending(x As HighScores, y As HighScores) As Integer
    Return y.score.CompareTo(x.score)
End Function
```

The code to sort would then look like this:

```
highscore.Sort(AddressOf CompareHighScoresByScoreDescending)
```

When comparing objects for sorting purposes, the convention is to use -1, 0 and 1 to represent relative positions.  That's what `CompareTo` does and thus that's what our comparison method does here.  If the object you call `CompareTo` on is conceptually less the object you pass in then the result is -1.  1 means the first object is greater than the second and 0 means they are equal.  That method could be rewritten like so:

```
Private Function CompareHighScoresByScoreDescending(x As HighScores, y As HighScores) As Integer
    If y.score < x.score Then
        Return -1
    ElseIf y.score > x.score Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

It's obviously more succinct to use the existing `IComparable` implementation of the `Integer` type though, i.e. that `CompareTo` method.

By the way, your code could use some improvements in other areas.  Firstly, `HighScores` is not an appropriate name for that class.  It represent a single thing so the name should not be plural and it doesn't actually represent a high score in and of itself.  A more appropriate name would be `PlayerScore` as that more accurately describes what it represents.

Secondly, your `List` variable actually does represent more than one object, i.e. a list that contains multiple items, so it's name should be plural.  It also does actually represent high scores so it should be named `highScores`.

Finally, it is almost universally bad practice to expose member variables publicly.  You should absolutely be using properties in that class:

As a bonus, if you're using VS 2015 or later then you can also replace `String.Format` with string interpolation.

```
Public Class PlayerScore

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Score As Integer

    Public Sub New(name As String, score As Integer)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Score = score
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name}, {Score}"
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for!